# Where is the runtime entry point for BitcoinXT (main function not found)?

Tags: c++, bitcoin

It is my understanding that all C++ programs require a main() function; however, I am unable to find a main() function in the main.cpp file of the BitcoinXT repository (I assume that the same question would apply to the Bitcoin repository as they share the same code base). The closest thing I can find is the initialization of a variable named cs_main on line 47 of the main.cpp file.

```
CCriticalSection cs_main;
```

So what's the trick?

1) How does the program compile and run without a main function?

2) Which function is used as the entry point instead of main, when main does not exist?

Alternate question:  Is the main function stored in a file other than main.cpp?

Comment: Is BitcoinXT a library or a program?  As a library, you need to create the `main()` function and call Bitcoin functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BitcoinXT does have a main function, it's located in [src/qt/bitcoin.cpp](https://github.com/bitcoinxt/bitcoinxt/blob/2b918beb7e822fdc4450165e2a0162a75b5160ff/src/qt/bitcoin.cpp)

Comment: Thank you so much!  I saw the main.cpp file and could not understand why the function did not exist there.  Again, I really appreciate your help with this!